# Input filtering using scanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I want to filter input. I don't know what is the best way. I want words starting with alpha-bates to be read. For example, if the input is:

```
This is 1 EXAMPLE1 input.
```

The string should be like this:

```
This is  EXAMPLE1 input
```

What is the easiest way to filter input like this?

I tried using `"%[a-zA-Z]s"`, but it not working.

Comment: ...but your second string also includes a non-alpha char ('1').

Comment: @reuben I edited the question. Words starting with alpha-bates.

Comment: what you tried, and what doesnt work?

Comment: @BЈовић I tried using "%[a-zA-Z ]s" as filter in scanf. But it is not working as expected.

Comment: scanf() probably isn't the right tool for this.  Have you tried copying the string into a new buffer, filtering as you go?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14539

Comment: @reuben By copying it and doing manually filter can be done. But I was thinking if it is possible using scanf.

Comment: @VivekGoel Yeah was thinking of something else ;)

Comment: I dont get it. What exactly have you tried_

Answer (score 2):

Your scan string `"%[a-zA-Z]s"` probably isn't want you think it is. Drop that trailing `s`.

`"%[a-zA-Z]"` will scan a string consisting entirely of lower and uppercase letters. So numbers will be discounted. However, you want to scan alpha-numeric strings that begin with a lower or uppercase letter. `scanf` doesn't provide a facility to look for a string in that way. You can, instead, scan for an alpha-numeric string with `"%[a-zA-Z0-9]"`, and then drop the scanned input if it the first character of the string is numeric.

Using `scanf` is tricky for various reasons. The string may be longer than you expect, and cause buffer overflow. If the input isn't in the format you expect, then `scanf` may fail to advance past the unexpected input. It is usually more reliable to read the input into a buffer unconditionally, and parse the buffer. For example:

```
const char *wants
    = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
std::string word;
while (std::cin >> word) {
    if (!isalpha(word[0])) continue;
    std::string::size_type p = word.find_first_not_of(wants);
    word = word.substr(0, p);
    //... do something with word
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a different direction than scanf.  Unless this is a homework problem, there's no good reason to force use of it.  If anything, it's frequently best to avoid it, for the reasons you mention.

Comment: @reuben: Yes, it is very difficult to use correctly with free form input. It can be used on mechanically generated tabulated output, and may even be said to be suitable for that if input performance is not an issue. Regards